# UICollectionView in horizental scrolling Next button click to go right cell and allow scrolling only to left cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, horizontalscrollview

I am making a **quiz** app(In swift) for that is used collection view and the collection view cell height and width is a full view. When the user reading 1st question (In-Cell 1) I want to disable scrolling because we don't allow the user to see the next question (i mean 2nd Question). when the user clicks the next button it will navigate to 2nd question (This next button functionality working fine). here is the main problem. I want to read 1 Question now for this time I want the user to allow the scroll to cell 1 and 2 but not to 3rd cell because he didn't click next Button in cell2. I want to implement like this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say that you could create an array with all the questions that you have, and another one with the questions to show, and once the user matches your logic to go to the next question, add it to the end of the array.

Comment: could you please explain more briefly with code ??